# Мониторинг клавиатуры в Python

Tags: python, клавиатура, мышь, мониторинг

Появилась задача мониторинга нажатий на клавиатуру со свернутой программой.
К примеру **запущен бесконечный цикл**, как прервать его, либо завершить процесс полностью при свернутой программе, учитывая что **курсор находится вне контроля пользователя**. Еще лучше что бы это была комбинация клавиш.
Если кто знает, прошу употребить пару хэштегов, дабы объяснить те или иные модули, ведь для работы нужно понимание ^-^. Для движения мыши используется команда  **win32api.mouse_event**

Comment: [pyHook](https://github.com/Answeror/pyhook_py3k)